# SQL in Wordpress Template

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I need to add some custom functionality in my wordpress template, this is the code I am using which works perfectly but...

I realise the query isn't secure, how would i make this particular code secure to prevent injection? I have done the research but I'm unaware how to incorporate it into this code.

Also you can see I can connected to the Wordpress database manually, is there a faster more secure way using a built in Wordpress function?

```
<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("$localhost","$user","$pass");
$sel_db=mysql_select_db("$name", $conn);

if(isset($_POST['getAjax'])) {
    //select membership
    $sel_membership_users="SELECT * FROM wp_pmpro_memberships_users ".
        "WHERE user_id=".$user_ID." AND  status='active'";
    $sel_membership_query=mysql_query($sel_membership_users);
    $sel_membership_arr=mysql_fetch_array($sel_membership_query);

    if ($sel_membership_arr['membership_id']!='0' ||
        $sel_membership_arr['membership_id']!='4') {

        //select user
        $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
        $sel_users="SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE ID=".$user_ID;
        $sel_query=mysql_query($sel_users);
        $sel_arr=mysql_fetch_array($sel_query);

        //update limit
        if ($sel_arr['download_limits']<=9) {
            $updt="UPDATE wp_users SET download_limits=".
                $sel_arr['download_limits']."+1 where ID=".$user_ID;
            $updt_query=mysql_query($updt);
            //exit;
        }
        else {
            echo "You can not download now.";
        }
    }
    exit();
}
//reset download_limits to zero on month start
$today=date('d');
if($today=='01') {
    $updt="UPDATE wp_users SET download_limits=0";
    $updt_query=mysql_query($updt);
}
```

Comment: Firstly, stop using `mysql`, use `mysqli` http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php.  Secondly, in the same manual you will find `mysqli_real_escape_string`, that's how you sanitize your input. Even better, learn about prepared statements and use PDO.  Even better still, use WP's built in database class.

Comment: [You should really look at this if willing to use WP API's](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Comment: as above use wpdb, but it looks like you are using a custom file for ajax, wp has a method for ajax as well where wpdb will be available for use. Also in general if using wpdb you will need to sanitize $user_ID for use, this is a good habit to have, but you seem to have not set user_ID in your first query?